# Get field names in attribute table with Python

Tags: python, geopandas, vector-layer

I have a geopackage file, with a layer called "MyLayer". Within this I have an attribute table with approx 20 attributes.

I can read in each attribute individually like:

```
import geopandas as gpd

geopkg = gpd.read_file('MyGeoPkg.gpkg', layer='MyLayer')
A = geopkg['AttributeA']
```

However, I have multiple GPKG files and they may have a different number of attributes, that may have different names.

I'd like to automatically get a list like:

```
listOfAttributes = ['AttributeA', 'AttributeB', 'AttributeC']
```

so I could then do:

```
for l in listOfAttributes:
    data = geopkg[l]
```

Is there a way of getting a list of the field names from the layer so I can iterate over them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You effectively want to iterate over columns of GeoDataFrame, which you can get using `geopkg.columns`.

So assuming you don't want to iterate over geometry field:

```
for col in geopkg.columns.drop('geometry'):
    data = geopkg[col]
```

Comment: Fiona.listlayers('MyGeoPkg.gpkg') returns the layer, which gives me 'MyLayer', it doesn't return me the attribute fields - unless I'm not using it as intended...?

Comment: Oh sorry, I got confused by your code. I will edit accordingly.

Comment: my variable 'listOfLayers' was confusing. Will change to 'listOfAttributes'. Accepting as answer because it was the first and keeps it within geopandas/fiona

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/220844/get-field-names-of-shapefiles-using-gdal). There are several examples here, but this one works the best for my case:

```
source = ogr.Open('MyGeoPkg.gpkg')
layer = source.GetLayer()
schema = []
ldefn = layer.GetLayerDefn()
for n in range(ldefn.GetFieldCount()):
    fdefn = ldefn.GetFieldDefn(n)
    schema.append(fdefn.name)
print(schema)
```